# Is OpenReports compatible with Java 1.5?

Tags: java, report, scheduling

According to the Installation Guide at http://oreports.com/docs/or-install-guide-3.0.html , OpenReports requires JDK 1.5 or higher.

However, having followed the instructions up to the point of the ANT build, I'm seeing the following error returned:

```
[javac] C:\My Documents\Reference\BI Tools\OpenReports\openreports-tomcat\openreports\src\org\efs\openreports\engine\QueryReportEngine.java:36: cannot access org.displaytag.tags.ColumnTag
[javac] bad class file: C:\My Documents\Reference\BI Tools\OpenReports\openreports-tomcat\openreports\WebRoot\WEB-INF\lib\displaytag-1.2-patched-for-itext-2.1.0.jar(org/displaytag/tags/ColumnTag.class)
[javac] class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
[javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[javac] import org.displaytag.tags.ColumnTag;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] 1 error
```

Having googled the "wrong version" message, it appears that this is because the class is specific to Java 1.6.

So - as the title of this question says - does anyone know whether OpenReports is compatible with Java 1.5, and if so, what am I doing wrong to get this error?

Answer (score 1):

There were issues cropping-up with using jdk 1.6.  Exceptions containing:
Pivot] 13 Jan 2011 09:18:53,469 ERROR [Session ] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext#listenerStart: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xfireReportService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-webservices.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportService' while setting bean property 'serviceBean'; nested exception i

One of the developers posted that it was because jdk 1.6 was not yet supported in OR 3.0 and that the fix was going to be submitted in Dec.2010.  I am getting this error with OR 3.2 and jdk 1.6 but I haven't heard as to whether this has to do with the jdk 1.6 issue.  Mine, however, does compile using jdk 1.6 it just doesn't run.

To answer your question ... maybe?  I haven't gotten a response on their forum yet.

Comment: So it sounds as though there are OpenReports issues with both Java 1.5 *and* 1.6.